# Solving an separable ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $\cos(y)\sin(t)\frac{dy}{dt}=\sin(y)\cos(t)$

(This ODE is taken from 'Differential Equations
and Their Applications' by Martin Braun)

The ODE above is separable if $\sin(y) \neq 0$ and so, we can verify that $y(t)=2k\pi; k \in \mathbb{Z}$ are solutions of the given ODE; now if $y$ isn't any of these solutions, then by continuity of $y$, there exists $x_0$ and $h>0$ s.t.:

\begin{align*}
y(x) \neq 2k\pi \;\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}; x \in J=(x_0-h,x_0+h)
\end{align*}
So in such an  $J$, we can write the following:
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\cos(y)}{\sin(y)}\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{\cos(t)}{\sin(t)} \\[9pt] \iff& \frac{d(log(|\sin(y)|)}{dt}=\frac{d(log(|\sin(t)|)}{dt} \\[9pt] \iff&
log(|\sin(y)|)=log(|\sin(t)|)+k; k \in \mathbb{R} \\[9pt] \iff&
|\sin(y)|=e^k|\sin(t)|; k \in \mathbb{R} \\[9pt] \iff&
\sin(y)=c\sin(t); c \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\} \\[9pt] \iff&
y=\arcsin(c\sin(t)); c \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}
\end{align*}

And now the general solution could be summed up as:
$$ y=\arcsin(c\sin(t)); c \in \mathbb{R} \lor y(x)=2k\pi; k \in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$$

Is this the complete list of solutions ? In the answers to the exercises, they only consider $y=\arcsin(c\sin(t))$.